# Error updating entity - Symfony 3

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

There's something very very wrong with Doctrine/MySQL or I'm just completly dumb. I'm trying to execute a simple update query on Question entity:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| form_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| question_type | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| validation    | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| required      | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

With:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('order', IntegerType::class)    
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('questionType', TextType::class)
        ->add('validation', TextType::class)
        ->add('required', CheckboxType::class)     
    ;         
}
```

and

```
...
$em->persist($question);
...
```

I'm getting this error:

Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException: "An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE questions SET order = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [1, 12]

Every other field validates with no problem!

When I'm trying to run the same query in the console, this is the result:

```
mysql> UPDATE questions SET order=1 WHERE id=14;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order=1 WHERE id=14' at line 1
```

When I run the same query in Workbench, everything is ok:

```
UPDATE `questions` SET `order`='2' WHERE `id`='7';
```

Finally, updating another column in this table (also integer!), like so:

```
update questions set form_id=5 where id=7;
```

Goes as expected.

What is going on?

EDIT:
To simplify, why this works:

```
UPDATE questions SET form_id=5 WHERE id=7;
```

And this doesn't:

```
UPDATE questions SET order=3 WHERE id=7;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word for Mysql
That's why it runs when (escaped with backticks)
It goes without saying that choosing another name would be safer
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql) for more informations

Comment: Right, I just got it work renaming to (random name) orderx ;) I dodn't think of that because order is always followed by BY. So is BY also reserved? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, well I guess the language parser is triggered whenever there is `order` followed by a space